# Cancelling propagation of the onchange event of a select control

Tags: javascript, html

I have a select control nested inside a table cell.  The Table row that contains the table cell has an onclick event.  When I click on the select control to change the value the onclick event of the row is fired.

I've tried using the stoppropagation method on the onchange event but it doesn't seem to work.

Below is my code

```
xxxxxxx.Helper.DDGoto = function (o, e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var path = $(o).val();

    if (path != null) {
        this.Goto(path);
    }
}



   <tr onclick="somemethod()">
     <td>some text</td>
     <td>
      <select onchange="xxxxxxx.Helper.DDGoto(this, event)">some options</select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Your `xxxxxxx.Helper.DDGoto` is _not_ fired by `click`, but by `change`. So the `e.stopPropagation();` inside is never executed!

Comment: Add the `$('select').on('click', function(e) { e.stopPropagation();})` and it works

Comment: Is this because onchange and click are not the same event type?

Answer (score 2):

The event triggered with the `onchange` event on your `select` is not firing the `onclick` event on your `tr`, they are not of the same type. They are two different events. That's also why stopping propagation of the `onchange` event does not stop the `onclick` event to be triggered.

You should instead in your `onclick` handler check if the `select` element was clicked or not:

```
somemethod = function (event) {
  if (event.target.nodeName === 'SELECT') {
    // The select was clicked, stopping...
    return;
  }

  // The select was not clicked, go ahead...
}
```

To get the event in your handler, you need to change your declaration to:

```
<tr onclick="somemethod(event)">
```

I used the `nodeName` property for the example, but you could also use the `type` property of the target or any other method to detect if the select was clicked or not.

You can check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4heLtbbf/) for an example.

Comment: For typescript `(event.target as HTMLDivElement).nodeName === 'SELECT'`

Answer (score 1):

When you click on select tag, both onChange and onClick event is fired!
I solved this by creating a onClick handler along side onChange handle and then calling e.stopPropogation() function.

Worked for me!

```
 <select (click)="StopPropogation($event)"  (change)="textureChanged($event,i)" class="form-control" id="sel1">
                            <option  selected="isTextureSolid(nodule.texture)">solid</option>
                            <option selected="isTexturePartSolid(nodule.texture)">part-solid</option>
                            <option selected="isTextureNonSolid(nodule.texture)">non-solid</option>
                            </select>
```

Javascript code:

```
StopPropogation(e: Event) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  console.log('Click event stopped from propogating');
}

textureChanged(e: Event, i: number) {

  e.stopPropagation();
  console.log('textTure Changed');
  let btnId = 'save' + i.toString();
  document.getElementById(btnId).style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById(btnId).style.visibility = 'visible';

}
```